# Detect window scrolling only once Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to show an alert after the user has scrolled 200px downwards. Single time, no more.

```
$(window).scroll(function(){if($(this).scrollTop()>200){
                                alert("SQL code executed"); 

                                }
```

Using this code, the alert appears anytime, How can I make it to appear only once? I need to execute an sql query, but with this current code the sql can be executed so many times as long as the user moves the scroll in the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [unbind](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) the event before or after (I did it after) the execution of the SQL code.

See the below snippet.

```js
$(window).scroll( function(){  
   if($(this).scrollTop()>200){
       alert("SQL code executed"); 
          $(this).unbind("scroll");
   }
  }
);
```

```css
body {
  height:1800px;      
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Much better than keeping the event handler alive and requiring a constant boolean check for the rest of the page's lifetime.

Comment: Interesting. but my css styles of my site configuration doesnt allow `body: overflow:scroll;`. but is pretty clever, though

Comment: @joe: Pretty sure that was just for the demonstration. The JavaScript on its own should work. It's both simpler and more efficient (wildly!) than the other answers.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit is right. The CSS is just for demonstration purpose.

Comment: @joe, I've updated the answer removing the `overflow:scroll;`. You can try just the javascript code in your site and you will find out it works.

Comment: its perfect, thank you. I have this question, what would be the problem of having a constant boolean check for the rest of the page's lifetime?.

Comment: Thanks for reconsider, @joe. The onscroll event is fired several times when the user is scrolling the page. There is no reason to keep the event handler if you need to execute its code only once.

Answer (score 0):

Have a boolean variable that you reference.  Once it's true, don't call again.

```
var previousCalled = false;

$(window).scroll(function(){if($(this).scrollTop()>200 && !previousCalled){
                                alert("SQL code executed"); 
                                previousCalled = true;
                                }
```